# Get all string resources from XML resource file?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I have a resource file called `suggestions.xml` which is translated to a couple of languages. These XML files contain just `<string>` values.

Now, I'd like to retrieve all the strings in the current locale's `suggestions.xml` file. How do I do that? I know I can retrieve single strings by their ID's, but I'd like to get *all* the strings in the XML file instead.

Comment: can you please update if my solution worked for you or not ?

Comment: hi, do u mind telling if u managed to do this and how u did it?

Answer (score 7):

I wonder why would you need to do this. Still, you can use the generated `R` class to iterate over all kinds of resources.

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
String[] stringNames = new String[fields.length];
for (int  i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {           
    stringNames[i] = fields[i].getName();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Wouldn't this include all string resources, not just the ones in `suggestions.xml`?

Comment: Sorry my bad, still haven't woke up apparently :) You're right - this will list you all strings, not only the ones in your suggestions file. Can you perhaps prefix your strings in this file with some prefix and then search for it in the list of all strings?

Comment: Prefixes are a possibility, yes. It feels a bit redundant though if all the resources I want are stored in a single file. I'll give it a try if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your strings like this.

```
 <string-array name="fruitcategory_array">

    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Bananas</item>
    <item>Mangoes</item>
    <item>Grapes</item>
    <item>Other</item>

 </string-array>
```

In your activity class, you can access them like the following.

```
String[] categories;

categories=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruitcategory_array);
```

Just store your Local Strings in an `Array` in your `suggestions.xml` file.

Comment: Does this solution work well with the localization? Are the `item`s in the same order in all the locales?

Comment: I'm not sure about localization, you can give it a try though.