# get ID of string from another values

Tags: android

I know the title is confusing,
But I have a persistent problem when trying to get id key of existing string from strings.xml

like this
I have three values folders:
values , values-fr, values-ar;

and I have one string id:

```
R.id.center
```

when printed in screen, this id show:
in values

```
"Center"
```

in values-fr

```
"Centre"
```

in values-ar

```
"وسط"
```

My question is:
Is there a way to retrieve the int id by passing `"Center" or "Centre" or "وسط" as parameter

Someting like "وسط".getId, or ("Centre").getId
I know these methods doesn't exist :)`

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I need a solution not a question

Comment: consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774447/get-all-string-resources-from-xml-resource-file and then just compare strings

Comment: You need a solution for a problem that you probably created. Thus the question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Tested and working. Includes locale-support now.

```
public void listValues() {
    Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();

    String[] locales = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();


    for (int x = 0; x < locales.length; x++) {
        System.out.println("checking for all ressources for the locale=" + locales[x]);
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("name=" + fields[i].getName() + " value=" + getLocalizedResources(this, new Locale(locales[x])).getString(fields[i].getInt(fields[i].getName())));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                System.out.println(".. catch it if you want it");
            } catch (RuntimeException rex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonNull
Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, Locale desiredLocale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf = new Configuration(conf);
    conf.setLocale(desiredLocale);
    Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
    return localizedContext.getResources();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this is not solve the main problem. Read my answer.

Comment: Of course it does. You should have basic-experience to modify my example to a working solution.

Comment: Oh gosh! Nope! You will never find "Center" string you use Arabic language

Comment: Ok.much better.But not enough . It is possible to setup string not only for locales but for , e.g., orientation.

Comment: Dont be lazy ;-) This is why getLocalizedResources has its own function. You can easy modify the configuration parameters to fit your needs (eg orientation, etc)

Comment: @Emanuel Thank you Emanuel for your reply but your answer didn't solve my problem 
I found a way to handle my
I am working on advertisement app based on JSON Doc database, so when a user send his advertisement as a String to the server, other users with differents locals can see this advertisement translated in their own languages
My solution is : instead of sending the string name(exp:"وسط" of the object, just send the id like this: (R.id.center+"")
then every locale will get the appropriate string by calling this id

Comment: This is not how it should be done since values are hardcoded strings. Use a local database for your case.